# Proof of an odd function plus an even function

Tags: functions, intuition

I was looking at the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#The_sum_of_even_and_odd_functions 
and it says that to prove an even function plus an odd function, we first have to re-write the f(x) as

$f(x)$ as $f(x)/2 + f(x)/2 + f(-x)/2 - f(-x)/2$

Why has f(x) been written like this? For example, where on earth did "+ f(-x)/2" and "- f(-x)/2" come from? I have my own idea as to where these functions have come from, and you can read my understanding of it below (and tell me if my thinking is correct or incorrect).
Secondly, I don't see why they have re-written the functions as being divided by two. Why have they done that? I feel that I could happily re-write the function f(x) as
$f(x)$ as $f(x)/ + f(x)/ + f(-x)/ - f(-x)/$
But would that be incorrect? If so, why?

**My thoughts to my questions:**

Is each function f(x) divided by 2 because f(x) is a function for all real numbers? If not, why is each function divided by 2 in this proof?

Secondly, why is the function of f(x) re-written in that form? Is it because:

an even function is $f(x)/2 = f(-x)/2$  which is $0 = f(x)/2 - f(-x)/2$

and an odd function is $f(x)/2 = -f(-x)/2$ which is $0 = f(x)/2 + f(-x)/2$

and these added together makes the 're-written f(x) function' $f(x)$ as $f(x)/2 + f(x)/2 + f(-x)/2 - f(-x)/2$ ?

If not, please do try to explain so I can understand this proof.
Thanks

Comment: Proof of what?${}$

Comment: Proof of an even function plus an odd function?

Comment: Do you mean that any function can be expressed as the sum of an even function and an odd function?

Comment: @GitGud I interpreted it as "Explain the above proof of why every function can be written as odd + even".

Comment: Also, you should care for the definition domain. For example, $\large{\rm f}\left(x\right) = \ln\left(x\right)$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Actually, that doesn't matter. If it is undefined, you can let the other functions be undefined at that point. Though, you're right in the sense that the sum will be defined in a larger domain. If so, then they strictly speaking are not the same function.

Comment: @CalvinLin It does matter, the property of evenness or oddness requires a symmetric domain.

Comment: Well, in Felix's example, we can have $g(x) = \frac{ \ln|x| } {2}$ and $g(x) = \sgn(x) \frac{ \ln |x| } {2} $. and $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ on the domain of $f$. We can even say that $g(0) = \{\text{elephant} \}$ if we wish.

Comment: @GitGud http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#The_sum_of_even_and_odd_functions
I am sorry if I am not being clear enough. I am just trying to write a proof for adding an even function to an odd function.
The first step on the wiki page I have linked is re-writing $f(x)$ and I just wanted to know why it has done it that way. I am not necessarily trying to prove that ANY/EVERY function can be expressed as the sum of an even and odd function... I just want to add them in a proof to help me understand something else.

Comment: @Polly : you should edit your question so it is clear exactly what you are asking, and not just explain it in your comments.  As far as I know, you can edit your question all you want.

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x)$ is not defined in a symmetric domain, we extend $f(x)$ such that it takes on values of 0 otherwise.

Suppose that $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$, where $g(x)$ is an even function and $h(x)$ is an odd function. Then,

$$f(-x) = g(-x) + h(-x) = g(x) - h(-x).$$

Hence, we may solve for $g(x), h(x)$ to obtain

$$ g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{2} + \frac{ f(-x) } { 2} , h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{2} - \frac{ f(-x) } { 2} $$

This approach motivates the function, and it remains to check that they satisfy the conditions. We can easily check that $g(x)$ is indeed an even function, and $h(x)$ is an odd function, and $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$, in the (extended) domain of $f(x)$, and in particular, the original domain of $f(x)$.

---

The idea of the proof you presented is that -

1) $f(x)$ can be rewritten in the following way

$$f(x) = [\frac{f(x)}{2} + \frac{ f(-x) } { 2} ] + [ \frac{f(x)}{2} - \frac{f(-x)} { 2} ].$$

This follows by just cancelling terms on the RHS. $_\square$

2) Show that the first term is an even function, and the second term is an odd function.

Let $ g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{2} + \frac{ f(-x) } { 2} $. Then $g(-x) = \frac{f(-x)}{2} + \frac{ f(-(-x) ) } { 2}  = \frac{f(x)}{2} + \frac{ f(-x) } { 2}  = g(x) $. Hence it is even.
Do the same for $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{2} - \frac{ f(-x) } { 2} $ to show that it is odd.$_\square$

Of course, this doesn't explain where we plucked those functions from.

Comment: @GitGud Ah, I didn't see that interpretation. Let me add it in.